# Typescript compiler to detect errors when accessing object properties via square brackets

Tags: typescript

**Is there a way to force Typescript compiler to detect errors when accessing object properties via square brackets?**

I am dealing with a legacy code where the object properties access was mostly done this way ( `obj['myProp']` instead of `obj.myProp` so I need to find a way to ad types. Here is the code example and this won't give me any error at compile time sadly :(, is there a way to make a compiler detect that property 'test' does not exists.

```
interface IPerson{
    name: string
}

let x: IPerson

x = { name: 'John' };

let y = x['test'];
```

Comment: While it doesn't prevent it entirely, I find that setting the `no-string-literal` TsLint rule greatly reduces occurrences of bracket notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x['test']` is specifically not checked under default compiler settings to ease migration from Javascript where `[]` is traditionally used for more dynamic access to objects.

If you turn on `noImplicitAny` you will get an error on this kind of access if the key is not in the object.

Comment: Tnx, this seems like a way to find all the occurrences and then I will need to refactor them to use . access. Is this what you suggest ?

Comment: @Hivaga No, the aceess will be checked just as if it were a `. ` access, no changes required. It's just where the access can't be proven type safe you will get an error.

Comment: Indeed, Typescript guru :). That is exactly what I need.